# Creating forms and html

Tags: javascript, forms

I want to create a basic form in HTML+JavaScript, how to create it?

Here's a HTML form created by me, JavaScript (snowing) I took from Internet

```js
     function myFunction(){
        var canvas = document.getElementByName("vardas");
        alert(canvas);
console.log(canvas);
    }
    
    window.onload = function(){
     //canvas init
     var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
     var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
     
     //canvas dimensions
     var W = window.innerWidth;
     var H = window.innerHeight;
     canvas.width = W;
     canvas.height = H;
    
    
     //snowflake particles
     var mp = 100; //max particles
     var particles = [];
     for(var i = 0; i < mp; i++)
     {
      particles.push({
       x: Math.random()*W, //x-coordinate
       y: Math.random()*H, //y-coordinate
       r: Math.random()*4+1, //radius
       d: Math.random()*mp //density
      })
     }
     
     //Lets draw the flakes
     function draw()
     {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
      
      ctx.fillStyle = "white";
      ctx.beginPath();
      for(var i = 0; i < mp; i++)
      {
       var p = particles[i];
       ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
       ctx.arc(p.x, p.y, p.r, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
      }
      ctx.fill();
      update();
     }
    
    
    
     //Function to move the snowflakes
     //angle will be an ongoing incremental flag. Sin and Cos functions will be applied to it to create vertical and horizontal movements of the flakes
     var angle = 0;
     function update()
     {
      angle += 0.01;
      for(var i = 0; i < mp; i++)
      {
       var p = particles[i];
       //Updating X and Y coordinates
       //We will add 1 to the cos function to prevent negative values which will lead flakes to move upwards
       //Every particle has its own density which can be used to make the downward movement different for each flake
       //Lets make it more random by adding in the radius
       p.y += Math.cos(angle+p.d) + 1 + p.r/2;
       p.x += Math.sin(angle) * 2;
       
       //Sending flakes back from the top when it exits
       //Lets make it a bit more organic and let flakes enter from the left and right also.
       if(p.x > W+5 || p.x < -5 || p.y > H)
       {
        if(i%3 > 0) //66.67% of the flakes
        {
         particles[i] = {x: Math.random()*W, y: -10, r: p.r, d: p.d};
        }
        else
        {
         //If the flake is exitting from the right
         if(Math.sin(angle) > 0)
         {
          //Enter from the left
          particles[i] = {x: -5, y: Math.random()*H, r: p.r, d: p.d};
         }
         else
         {
          //Enter from the right
          particles[i] = {x: W+5, y: Math.random()*H, r: p.r, d: p.d};
         }
        }
       }
      }
     }
     
     //animation loop
     setInterval(draw, 33);
    }
```

```css
    body {
     /*You can use any kind of background here.*/
     background: #6b92b9;
    }
    canvas {
     position: absolute;
     display: block;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>forms</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
    <script src="demo.js"></script>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </head>
    <body>
     your name:<br>
     <input type="text" name="vardas"><br>
     <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The form is created but I can't write on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add  `z-index: -10;` to canvas style.

```
canvas {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -10;
}
```

Comment: z-index:-10 works.!!!
so with z index js canvas is post under forms. ty!!

Comment: but how to make working form and snow on form. now everything is working but snow is under form. how to make snow on form?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'snow on form'? Do you want the snow to fall on inputs?

Answer (score 0):

Remove canvas tag from head and put in body
Edit as per your requirement

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>forms</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
<script src="demo.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" style="z-index:-10;"></canvas>
    your name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="vardas"><br>
    <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
    <!-- remove canvas tag from head and put in body-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: now works! thank you.
but now if you try this code in browser. you will see that snow is falling under form, it is imposibble to create form, that will snow on it?

Comment: make 10 inputs and you will see what happening, the snow is falling under form.

Comment: put canvas at the start of body above input tag and make z-index in negative